# Kafka Streams SIiding window implementation code example

Tags: apache-kafka, dsl, apache-kafka-streams

I have been trying to implement Sliding windows in Kafka using Streams DSL and I am not able to do so. Can anyone help me with a code example. I want to aggregate values for a particular period using sliding window approach.

I have searched confluent blogs and all but no code is there

Comment: Reading this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  will help you get the answer you need.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I believe Kafka Docs provide sufficient information about [sliding time windows](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#sliding-time-windows).

> Session windows are used to aggregate key-based events into so-called
>   sessions, the process of which is referred to as sessionization.
>   Sessions represent a period of activity separated by a defined gap of
>   inactivity (or “idleness”). Any events processed that fall within the
>   inactivity gap of any existing sessions are merged into the existing
>   sessions. If an event falls outside of the session gap, then a new
>   session will be created.
>
> The following code defines a session window with an inactivity gap of 5 minutes:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.SessionWindows;

// A session window with an inactivity gap of 5 minutes.
SessionWindows.with(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5));
```

Comment: I have gone through sessions window example. But I am concerned about sliding window. there is only theory which does not help the cause. I wish to do aggregation on a continuously streaming data and output the result for every window.